# Нужно считать строку до точки и подсчитать кол-во слов в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не понимаю где проблема в коде. Пытаюсь считать строку до точки в данном коде:

```py
s = 'Тестовая. Строка'
_str = ''
for i in range(len(s)):
    while s[i] != '.':
        _str += s[i]
print(_str)
```

Но ничего не выводит, прошу расписать чуть подробнее -- почему?

PS задачей запрещено использовать конструкцию `if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл `while` у вас выполняется всегда. Можно поменять на такое решение:

```
s = 'Тестовая. Строка'
_str = ''
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] != '.':
        _str += s[i]
    else:
        break
print(_str)
```

Для цикла `while`:

```
s = 'Тестовая. Строка'
_str = ''
counter = 0

while s[counter] != '.':
    _str += s[counter]
    counter += 1

print(_str)
```

Comment: забыл упомянуть, задачей запрещено использования конструкции if, у меня ступор ;(

Answer (score 3):

```
s = "Первая тестовая строка. Вторая строка."

res = len(s.partition(".")[0].split())

print(res)
>>> 3
```

---

пошагово:

`s.partition(".")` - разделит строку на три части: подстрока до первого встретившегося разделителя, сам разделитель (`"."`) и оставшаяся после разделителя часть строки:

```
In [9]: s.partition(".")
Out[9]: ('Первая тестовая строка', '.', ' Вторая строка.')
```

выберем подстроку до первого разделителя:

```
In [10]: s.partition(".")[0]
Out[10]: 'Первая тестовая строка'
```

`.split()` - разобъет строку на слова

```
In [11]: s.partition(".")[0].split()
Out[11]: ['Первая', 'тестовая', 'строка']
```

Comment: @byte_, добавил комментарии в ответ...